# Google Play Two Applications have same Application ID

Tags: android, google-play, publish

So there was an issue with my first application and the keystore, so I had to create a new project with a different package name.  Uploaded it to google play.. I have it time at first, but it has been days, when ever I try to download the new application, it just sends me to the old application.  Both apps are in Beta, and neither are fully published. The application status says published on the new verison, unpublished on old version.  Google does not allow you to remove applications or remove .apk from beta, so I can't remove it all together.  I did notice when I created the new application google play gave it an identical Application IDs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have u tried changing the hashkey?

Comment: Generate a new key and upload it to "new" app under the dev console.

Comment: Would this be the SHA1? If so, I created a new keystore and new SHA1 for the second application.